# Recursive equations vs. inference rules

Tags: logic, recursion

It seems to me that recursive equations can always be presented as inference rules.  For the forward direction, an example is addition over Peono numerals (built from $O$ and $S(\_)$)

$$
\begin{align}
add(O, m)    & = m \\
add(S(n), m) & = S(add(n, m))
\end{align}
$$

which can be also presented as

$$
\frac{ }{add(O, m) = m} \qquad \frac{add(n, m) = a}{add(S(n), m) = S(a)}
$$

Is the backward conversion (from inference rules to recursive equations) always possible?  If not, it seems inference rules more general, right?  Except the superficial difference between the presentations, is there any other deeper difference between the two?

Comment: One obvious rematk is that equality is itself based on the use of (implicit) inference rules that include reflexivity, symmetry and substitution of equals for equals in any context (which implies transitivity). Your second example is only an instance of that substitution rule for equality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inference rules are "more general". A recursive equation, actually any equation $E_1 = E_2$ is like an inference rule without premisses:
$$\frac{}{E_1 = E_2}$$
A general inference rule may have premisses, and so it is like a *conditional* equation.
Only very special kinds of inference rules may be equivalently expressed as equations. For instance, it seems difficult to express
$$\frac{a \bullet c = b \bullet c}{a = b}$$
and
$$\frac{add(x,add(y,z)) = add(x,z)}{add(y,z) = z}$$
as equations.

Comment: But isn't the resulting set defined as (smallest) fixpoint of a *recursive* function built from the inference rules?

Comment: @Raphael: I remember I have seen inference rules being used to present corecursion.

Comment: @AndrejBauer: According to the first sentence of your answer, the second rule in my example may be presented simply as $add(S(n), m) = S(add(n, m))$ with an empty set of premises.  Is there any difference between the two presentations?

Comment: Looking at your two examples, the second is an instance of the first with
$a=add(y,z)$, $b=z$ and $\bullet=\lambda x y.add(y,x)$. This said,
I tend to agree with you, but I do not know why, and you only say: "it
seems difficult", which is hardly a proof. - -
Suppose I postulate the unary operator $-$, and the nullary operator
$0$, and the equalities $c\bullet-c=0$ and $(a\bullet b)\bullet c=
a\bullet(b\bullet c)$ and $a\bullet 0=a$. Then I no longer need the
inference rule (that is pretty much how $\mathbb{Z}$ is actually
constructed). Well, I use the equality inference rules, always implicit.

Comment: @Raphael: what "resulting set" are you referring to? The set of derivable statements? You can define it either as a least point, or expicitly ("those statements for which there exists a finite derivation tree").

Comment: I can always come up with more insane rules -- you cannot win the game. Of course if you add more operators you might be able to do something about the first rule (cancelation law), but then you're completely changing everythin. What if $\bullet$ refers to some operation that does not have inverses but still has a cancelation law (for instance, consing for lists)? The whole question is a bit off the mark, by the way.

Comment: Of course you can. I am only saying that this is not convincing. At least to me.

Comment: @AndrejBauer Yes, that was what I meant. The only rigorous way to get to that fixpoint I have seen is via a (monotone) recursive function, so I'd argue that recursion *does* seem to be able to model all inductive definitions (which these here are).

Comment: I already mentioned one way (a derivation is a finite tree). Another rigorous way a la Gödel: a derivation is number encoding a finite tree where each leaf is an axiom and each node is an application of an inference rule.

Comment: Well, we could turn to categorical logic to make it water tight. But first we'd have to agree on what exactly we're doing. What is the most general form of an inference rule, for example? Compare *algebraic theory* (http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/algebraic+theory) and *essentially algebric theory* (http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/essentially+algebraic+theory), for example.

Comment: It seems to me that with inference rules we define some relation inductively. In logic, it is a relation between statements of the logic, in type systems it is a relation between program expressions and types, etc. With recursive definitions, one defines an `equality` relation for some constructs. It seems to me that one can define equality relation using inference rules, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

I think recursion is more fundamental than inference rules. Note that I mentioned recursion and not recursive equation.

Recursion can be defined as a property of definition of some concept where the definition uses/include/refer to the concept itself that was being described. Now this concept can be anything or can have any particular representation. It could be inference rules, equations, relations, functions etc. 
From this point of view recursions is more fundamental than inference rules or any other notations of concepts.

**UPDATE**

To be more precise as par the question, yes it is possible to convert a inference rule to recursive  equation if the inference rule is recursive.

Comment: Thanks for your input but you are not answering my question.

Comment: @day: If you mean "Is the backward conversion (from inference rules to recursive equations) always possible". Then answer is - Yes it is possible to do so if the inference rule is recursive.